# Deregistration of event handlers in Angular

Tags: angularjs, event-handling, angularjs-scope

I saw a piece of code in a controller recently that went something like:

```
.controller('foobar', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    var eventHandler = $rootScope.$on('some-event', function() {
        ...
    });

    // remove eventHandler
    $scope.$on('$destroy', eventHandler);
}]);
```

Questions:

1. Is executing the `eventHandler` "deregistration" function on `$scope`'s `$destroy` event necessary?
2. If yes, would executing the deregistration function on `$scope`'s `$destroy` event have been necessary if `'some-event'` was `$on` `$scope` instead of `$rootScope`?
3. How do I know when I need to execute a deregistration function? I understand detaching or unbinding events is common for cleanup in JavaScript, but what rules can I follow to know when to do this in Angular?

Any advice about understanding this snippet/"deregistration" would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Event handlers are only deregistered on controller's `$destroy` event when it is on that controller's `$scope`.
2. The deregistering would be unnecessary if it's on `$scope` since that's handled for you by Angular.
3. Generally if it's not tied to instance of the individual `element`, `controller`, or `service` you are listening on then that is when you need to handle deregistering yourself.

A good example is a directive that registers event listeners on the `$document`:

```
var module = angular.module('test', []);
module.directive('onDocumentClick', function directiveFactory($document) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var onDocumentClick = function () {
                console.log('document clicked')
            };

            $document.on('click', onDocumentClick);

            // we need to deregister onDocumentClick because the event listener is on the $document not the directive's element
            element.on('$destroy', function () {
                $document.off('click', onDocumentClick);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

In the example above the destroy method is necessary. The listener is bound to the `$rootscope` which means that even after the controller gets `$destroy`-ed the listener is still attached to the dom through the `$rootscope`. Every time the controller is instantiated a new eventhandler will be created so without the destroy method you will have a memory leak.

However if you bind the listener to the controllers `$scope` it will get destroyed along with the controller as the $scope gets destroyed so the listener has no connection to the dom thus making it eligible for garbage collection